# UnManaged option not available in google play developer console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Hi all in my google play developer console when I'm going to create In-app under in-app products section it is showing only 2 options (Managed Product, Subscription) So how can I create Un-managed product please help me..

[image]

Thank you..

Answer (score 7):

This is because In app billing ver 3 now supports only two product types:
[Managed](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#managed) and  [Subscriptions](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#subs)

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume)

> In Version 3, all in-app products are managed. This means that the
>   user's ownership of all in-app item purchases is maintained by Google
>   Play, and your application can query the user's purchase information
>   when needed. When the user successfully purchases an in-app product,
>   that purchase is recorded in Google Play. Once an in-app product is
>   purchased, it is considered to be "owned". In-app products in the
>   "owned" state cannot be purchased from Google Play. You must send a
>   consumption request for the "owned" in-app product before Google Play
>   makes it available for purchase again. Consuming the in-app product
>   reverts it to the "unowned" state, and discards the previous purchase
>   data.

Comment: i'm using Open IAB. So how can i imaplement..                                                             what is the solution for this problem..

Comment: what problem are you facing? I think an un managed in app product would now be a managed consumable product.

Comment: how can i send the consumption request to set "owned" or "unowned" purchase. is there any sample..

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Consume Haven't checked how it is done in Open IAB

Comment: This is confusing... so to make a good old consumable, we have to chose managed and then "unown" that IAP for that user right after purchase?

Answer (score 2):

In the In-app Billing Version 3, there are only two Product Types

1. *Managed Product*
2. *Subscription*

if you want to make it un-managed product than you have to do this dynamically

1. select *Managed Product*
2. After purchases finish just add following function to make this un-owned  (Un-managed Products) by default it is owned.

[Thanks to p-mercier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804095/in-app-billing-v3-android-non-consumable-items) for suggesting this solution and the following code:

> `mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);`

- Unowned = you can buy multiple times like game coins, life etc
- Owned    = can not buy multiple time work for one time like book purchases, songs etc

Still if you have same problem than check product_id it can't

> android.test.purchased

you have to put real product-id from developer console. See also: [Android in app purchase: Signature verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600664/android-in-app-purchase-signature-verification-failed)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of products available which have 3 categories

1) Managed Products

a) Non Consumable Managed Product

b) Consumable Managed Product

2) Subscriptions

In your case you should use Consumable Managed Product where it allows to purchase same product multiple time like coins for game play.
For more details please refer
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api#consume